# Trouble Setting CSS Image Background in Table Class

Tags: css, image, class, background, css-tables

I am trying to make a single table background using CSS, but I cannot get the table to form.  Here is my code example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-image:url('http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg');}

table.background { background: url('http://www.example.com/images/image2.gif') no-repeat; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="background" style="width:400px;height:500px;> <tr><td>
<h1>Hello World!</h1></td></tr></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Why don't I see the Hello World statement displayed in the output?

Comment: You really ought to use a text editor with syntax highlighting. It will catch this much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tables should NOT be used to make layout. table is meant to display data, not headers. use divs instead

Comment: @mmk: This really isn't an answer. Doesn't matter the use of tables, it doesn't answer the question. (I do agree with you, but a comment is the better use of mentioning this, not an answer)

Comment: apologizes for now provide any tutorial links - had to go offline, but as I can see you have managed to work it out

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing quote here:

```
<table class="background" style="width:400px;height:500px;>
                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a closing quote (") in your style attribute.

Try this:

```
<table class="background" style="width:400px;height:500px;"> <tr><td>
<h1>Hello World!</h1></td></tr></table>
```

Here it is working in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/onunoc/2/edit#preview